# How can one call programs that are not "rooted" in the operating system

Tags: command-line, php, lamp, php-cli

I am currently trying to install a php extension on my computer. I am in the process of developing a new site and I am using LAMPP. I used PECL to install the syck YAML extension so that I can parse YAML to a PHP array in a file that will run daily with cronjobs.

In the process of trying to install it, I broke LAMPP and had to re-install it, but I got the extension installed.  Here's the kicker!  The extension was installed on PHP5 that is called by the terminal.

If I:

```
# php ./politicianupdate.php
```

It runs as it should, but it is not using the php installation inside of lampp, which is a problem because the php being ran from the terminal is not linked up to my databases, which I need to keep the data current.

Two things I need to figure out: how I can call a .php file from the terminal using the php installation in lampp, and the other thing I need to know is how can I point a PECL/PEAR installation at the installation of php in lampp?

The output of whereis php is:

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /usr/share/php /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

Comment: What is the output of `whereis php` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I suggest you to use:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php ./politicianupdate.php
```

If is ok, then check with `ls -l /usr/bin/php` if is a symbolic link. If yes, and if you would like, remove it then create a new one to `/opt/lampp/bin/php`:

```
ln -sf /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Comment: This creates a hardlink, not a symlink. For a symlink, you need `-s`.

Comment: I did this, and now if I go to the directory that contains the php file I want to run and run this command: # php ./phpfile.php  I get an error: bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory.

Comment: @user27038 which command?

Comment: -sf rather than -f alone just fixed it.  Thank you.

Comment: The command was "php ./thephpfile.php"

Comment: I'd say my question is answered.  Now that the system's default link points at the correct instance of php I should be able to get that extension working on my own now.